# Page not found (404) No comments found matching the query

Tags: python, django

views,py:

```
class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comments
    fields = ['content']
    template_name = 'blog/comment_create.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        messages.success(self.request, 'You have made a comment')
        return super().form_valid(form)

class CommentUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Comments
    fields = ['content']
    template_name = 'blog/comment_update.html'

    def test_func(self):
        comment = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == comment.author:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def form_valid(self, form):
        messages.success(self.request, 'You have updated the post')
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from blog.views import home, about, PostListView, PostDetailView, PostCreateView, PostUpdateView, PostDeleteView, CommentCreateView, CommentUpdateView

urlpatterns = [
    # path('', home, name='blog_home'),
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog_home'),
    path('post/<int:pk>', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post_delete'),
    path('post/create/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post_create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/create_comment/', CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='comment_create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update_comment/<int:comment_id>', CommentUpdateView.as_view(), name='comment_update'),

    path('about/', about, name='blog_about'),
]
```

models.py:

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(to=Post, related_name='comments',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Comment by {self.author} for {self.post.title}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.post.pk})
```

that is fom post template:

```
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
    <article class="media content-section">
    <div class="small text-muted">Comment by {{ comment.author }}</div>
            <a href="{% url 'comment_update' pk=object.pk comment_id=comment.pk %}">{{ comment.content }}</a>
        <div class="small text-muted"> Posted on {{ comment.date_posted }}</div>
    </article>

{% endfor %}
```

that is an error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46hch.png)

I dont understand why im getting 404 error, maybe there is something wrong with my view by i cant really understand what. I have tried changing it but nothing worked. I have never worked with multiple arguments in the url maybe that could be the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django detailview get\_queryset and get\_object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52551257/django-detailview-get-queryset-and-get-object) You want to look at the third point of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52551257/django-detailview-get-queryset-and-get-object/52551987#52551987), currently what is happening is that the view is trying to get a `Comments` object which has the primary key of the `Post` related to it.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Is it really OK, to use `/post/` in the URL to differentiate between requests verbs?</strike>  Edit: post probably meant post as in blogpost. I think it's still too much clutter since a comment id is enough.

Also, now I see that the URL match `path('post/<int:pk>/update_comment/<int:comment_id>', CommentUpdateView.as_view(), name='comment_update'),` you have `<int:pk>` which is probably automatically used to on `comment = self.get_object()` meaning you where trying to get a comment with the ID of the post, thus the error.

Now that you changed it it works because you're using `path('comments/<pk>/update/', CommentUpdateView.as_view(), name='comment_update'),` and `<pk>` is correctly assigned.

Probably, someone will correct me if I'm wrong.

### Old answer

If you define a `post()` method inside your `CommentUpdateView` class it'll use that when you send a POST request. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36860175/5640517

You could also use decorators for function based views. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69693779/5640517

I'm only mentioning this as I see your sending a GET request according to your image.

With the code I can see I can only assume that the error happens at `comment = self.get_object()` are you sure that `self.get_object()` works fine and that there's a comment with the id 4?

Comment: I just deleted test func and the same error appears. Maybe you can suggest anything else?

Comment: I don't believe that `post` is supposed to be the request method over there. It probably means a "Post" in the context of a social media / blog site.

Comment: You're most likely right :P

Answer (score 0):

I did it another way because I couldn't figure out how to do it like it was in the thread. I did it like this and everything worked fine:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # path('', home, name='blog_home'),
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog_home'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post_delete'),
    path('post/create/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post_create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/comments/create/', CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='comment_create'),
    path('comments/<pk>/', CommentDetailView.as_view(), name='comment_detail'),
    path('comments/<pk>/update/', CommentUpdateView.as_view(), name='comment_update'),
    path('comments/<pk>/update/', CommentDeleteView.as_view(), name='comment_delete'),

    path('about/', about, name='blog_about'),
]
```